# How to rewrite link text in reCAPTCHA form? (localization issue)

Tags: javascript, localization, recaptcha

There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?id=94) which prevents all the reCAPTCHA widget being translated.
The "Play sound again" and "Download sound as MP3" links don't translate when using pre-defined non-english translations like "es" but obviously works fine for my own translations, e.g. for zh.

### Is there any way around this?

#### Can I rewrite the links in JavaScript?

(*I'm asking for code*)

#### Or can I override the predefined translations for languages like German, Spanish, etc. with my own?

Comment: Perhaps you may need to customise the "I'm not a robot" text to whatever text you want. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826939/new-google-recaptcha-how-to-change-text-im-not-a-robot/43169416#43169416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en-GB/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n) says you can override the translation by populating the `custom_translations` attribute of the `RecaptchaOptions`.

Comment: Yes. I just did in there very quickly. I only gave translations for `play_again` and `cant_hear_this`.