# New Google reCaptcha: How to change text "I'm not a robot"

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I've installed the latest Google reCaptcha tool on our yoga website. Now the users are confused about the text "I'm not a robot" that appears next to the checkbox.

Most of our users do not know what the word "robot" means in this context and they think the form is broken. They also feel less safe using our form as it is weird to see the word "robot" on a yoga website.

How do I change the text "I'm not a robot" to something else that the users understand?

The docs appear silent on this point...

Also, it seems like the contents of the reRecaptcha are completely locked down via remote JS and CSS. I've unsuccessfully tried using the following javascript to change the text for Googles `recaptcha-anchor-label`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#recaptcha-anchor-label").text("Something different.");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization ?

Comment: @MarcB That is the 'old' recaptcha docs.

Comment: Nu, please send reply to this if you find out. I also would like to know. Thanks.

Comment: There is also a thread in the google group for the New reCaptcha here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/change$20the$20text/recaptcha/sLFBdhneh6E/u6M_SG2fsXoJ

Comment: What are you building your website on?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back to this old question - there is now an invisible version of the reCAPTCHA widget that allows you to design the UI on your own. You can bind the execution of the challenge to a button you've created or invoke it programmatically in the background.

I'm citing the docs page here for quick reference, you can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible).

> The necessary attributes are a class name 'g-recaptcha', your site key in the data-sitekey attribute, and the name of a JavaScript callback to handle completion of the captcha in the data-callback attribute.

Head:

```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
   <script>
     function onSubmit(token) {
       document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
     }
   </script>
```

---

Body:

```
  <form id='demo-form' action="?" method="POST">
    <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callck='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
    <br/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 36):

**It is possible to change "I'm not a robot"** in Google Recaptcha into a different language by using [language codes](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language) for the **hl** script parameter.

This is how you force Spanish, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es">
```

Source: [Google ReCaptcha Docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config)

Comment: This does not answer the question about how to change the text from "I am not a robot" to something else that makes sense to my users.  Translating it to another language would confuse my users more. `yo no soy un robot`

Comment: If in your application.rb you have a list of languages and in your view a button o select to choose between them, you can interpolate your variable locale to make the script access the language you have chosen. Application.rb `config.i18n.available_locales = %i[es en]`
Your view file `script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=#{I18n.locale.to_s}"` It worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 4):

It is currently impossible using their tool.  If you want to use a different method of stopping robots:  Uninstall reCaptcha, and use something you have control over, maybe a simple randomized question and answer that pertains to yoga.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  Do you know whether Google has plans to make it more editable in the future?

Comment: The reference is Google's API documentation, which I assumed you already had: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

I do not know Google's plans.

Comment: For the people who downvote this answer, don't shoot the messenger!  I can't help it they coded it that way.

Comment: Fair enough. But your "answer" doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prohibits any script (that's on your site) trying to access an iframe (the captcha) that has another origin (Google server).

We should have no problem running the code below if we own both servers :)

```js
$( ".g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe" ).contents().find( "#recaptcha-anchor-label" ).text('Custom Text');
```

Answer (score -1):

**I used client side captcha here is my code.its working fine for my portal.**

```
 this.canvas = document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' ) as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var context = this.canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height );
    var alpha = [];
    alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
         '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        var a = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var b = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var c = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var d = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var e = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var f = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
        var g = alpha[Math.floor( Math.random() * alpha.length )];
    }
    this.captchaCode = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;
    var ctext = this.captchaCode;
    this.loginForm.controls['captcha'].setValue( this.captchaCode.replace( /\s/g, "" ) );
```

**Here is I am drawing canvas image**

```
 /*Text to image captcha */
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage( imageObj, 0, 0 );
        context.font = "24px arial";
        context.fillText( ctext, 84, 32 );
    };
    imageObj.src = 'assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/captcha2.jpg';
```

Comment: This does NOT (at all) answer the question.